# How do I abstract these rxjava observable calls into a separate class?

Tags: android, mvvm, refactoring, rx-java, mvp

I am reaching the point of crowded classes...

How Can I abstract these rxjava calls into separate classes and
then only make the subscription inside this Activity?

```
   package market.loqoo.food.ui.Activity;
   ........
   public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
   .....
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ......
    final LocationRequestBuilder locationRequestBuilder = new LocationRequestBuilder(this);
    locationRequestBuilder.setReturnDefaultLocationOnError(false);
    locationRequestBuilder.addLastLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, new LocationTime(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS), false)
            .addRequestLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, new LocationTime(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .setDefaultLocation(new Location(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER))
            .create()
            .........
   .........
   .........
  addressObservable = locationProvider.getUpdatedLocation(locationRequest)
            .compose(bindToLifecycle())
            .flatMap(new Func1<Location, Observable<List<Address>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<Address>> call(Location location) {
                    Log.d(TAG + "lastLocation", location != null ? location.toString() : "Location is empty");
                    Log.d(TAG + "last loc t", Long.toString(location.getTime()));
                    if (location != null) {

  }
```

Comment: Move the code needed for constructing Observable in a separate class, and provide access to it with getter method. What's the problem?

Comment: Using this sample repository you can learn more about MVP mixture with dagger: http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel

Comment: @maxost...yeah i need this understanding. soo...what put the whole obervable code i have in the mainactivity in a class as function returning observable? put the subscribe in there as well...whats the structure look like of the class returning the observable??